# How to identify photos taken in a specific room

Tags: computer-vision, indoor-positioning-system

Random users take random photos in buildings. We will never met these users nor control what photos they take. This happens over time. I'd like an algo that can match photos taken in seprate rooms.

I can find geo clusters and find photos around those points...then grab bearings from jpeg data...etc

An algogs for room limits i should know? Thx

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do this. First is to index every room and *make sure the camera follows this index* which has the rooms name and camera direction listed by each index.
 The second solution is to put identifiable object in each room on each wall.
 No 2 objects are alike. Does not each room already have unique objects?

Comment: Thx sparky... but we have to do this purely from jpeg data / computer vision. Im trying more like finding geo location clusters per room....find bearing directions from jpeg data

Comment: Good luck with that. It seems that your making it much more complicated than it needs to be, like you need GPS coordinates, etc.